# How to calculate the angles between the faces of a twisted prism

Tags: geometry

Let's say I have a twisted prism with square bases. Its vertices are the same as a regular square antiprism with unit side length. How would I calculate the angles between the sides of the twisted prism?
 [The prism would look something like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0cLL.png)

Comment: Compute the coordinates of the vertices, define the relevant vectors for the edges in question, normalize them, then compute the dot product and solve for $\theta$.